# Accessibility and user input

Tags: accessibility

I'm planning to build a sharepoint intranet portail that must respects :
- the WCAG AA level 
- the current draft version of the WAI-ARIA rules
- the RGAA (a french law)

I've seen in a MS presentation that SP 2010 OOB respects these standards, which is quite a good news.

My questions :

- the HTML markup produce by SharePoint respects these standards, but what about user input ?
- especially, when a user insert a picture in a rich content, is there a way to force him to fill the title, the description, etc. ?
- Is there a way to clean up html manually entered
- ...
- in fact, is there ways to ensure (or at least guide) the user input is also respectful of these standards ?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML produced by SharePoint 2010 is a great improvement over the output of the SP2007 version, but it is not perfect. If you want to achieve WCAG you will probably still need to do some work, depending on what product features you use.

HTML that is input by the user is still an issue. At least it is not as bad as SP2007 which would actually take valid user input and break it. The SharePoint 2010 editor shouldn't make it any worse, but there is no mechanism to prevent markup that breaks the accessibility guidelines. There is a feature in the HTML editor to do a bit of clean-up to XHTML, but that is only part of the story. Ther is no way to impose this automatically or globally.

There are third-party products available, such as Hi-Software's Compliance Sheriff. This will check your markup and report errors, but it won't actually fix it for you. Don't expect these kinds of product to be cheap.

There are also third party rich-edit controls that may generate better HTML, that might be worth investigating.

Whatever you do, there are some accessibility rules that are really beyond automated tooling and will ultimately need manual checking.

Comment: thx... it will be a challenge for years to come, here in France, as public administration must be wcag AA compliant (because of laws)